# jQuery Colorbox Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, button, colorbox

I'm trying to use jQuery Colorbox as a lightbox but the left, right and close buttons are not showing up at the bottom (click "dasdsadsa"):

http://zero6media.com/gee/wordpress/joes-calculator/

However, if I use the same code in a fiddle it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/4k1ty7wf/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a[class='web']").colorbox({width: "600px", height: "600px", maxWidth: "95%", maxHeight: "95%", html: "Hello", opacity: ".75",
rel: "group1", current: 0});
});
```

Why are the buttons not showing up on my first page?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors... You are missing control images for  colorbox. Correct colorbox image path.

Comment: No image is missing because it works fine in the fiddle using the same code. There are no console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some resource are not loaded in your actual web page

[image]

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1968Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi)
http://zero6media.com/gee/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/51.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://mymoviesdb.jgportfolio.com/css/wufoo.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I think one of them is responsible for this CSS property that you added in jsFiddle manually

```
        #cboxPrevious,#cboxNext,#cboxClose,#cboxSlideshow{position:absolute;bottom:-29px; background:url(http://www.jgportfolio.com/images/colorbox/controls.png) no-repeat 0px 0px; width:23px; height:23px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxPrevious{left:0px; background-position: -51px -25px;}
```

Your actual page is missing this property. I think that's because of those missing css links. Make sure all your css script paths are okay. Check in browser's 'inspect element' to ensure if they are added properly.

Comment: Hi AtanuCSE, check again. I fixed the console errors. They had nothing to do with the jQuery Colorbox.

Comment: ok I found out what was wrong. I just had to remove the extra spacing in the CSS as WordPress was omitting it. Apparently, WordPress doesn't like extra returns and indented spacing. I accepted your answer because it's what led me to the solution. Thank you. :)